# Avoid scrolling to top after loading content with jquery

Tags: jquery, load

I have this piece of code where I simulate tabs. It is working perfectly but every time I load a page clicking on a link in the "abas" div, the page scrolls back to the top. My while solution (ugly) was to to call a function after load to scrolls the page to the anchor "abas". What is going on here?

Here is the code:

```
<ul id="abas">
<li><a href="buscapage.php">Busca por práticas</a></li>
<li><a href="catpage.php" class="off">Categorias</a></li>
</ul>

$('#abas a').click(function(event) {        
  var $loader = '<img src="img/interface/loader.gif" class="loader" alt="" />',
  $pagina = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#get').html($loader).load($pagina, function(){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#abas').offset().top},'slow'); //solution =(
  });
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent does not avoid this to happen  
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you need to do on at the end of the click event function is return false.  Very similar to how you would subscribe to the click event on a hyperlink or button, and want to handle all of the execution in the event, thus, not let the browser take over and execute the click itself once your code has completed.

Comment: How tall is your page?  when setting the html on the #get control, does it shrink down to zero pixels (before new html is actually applied), causing your page to become so small that it no longer spans multiple pages?  If this is the case, setting a minwidth css value to that control so it remains at a resonable size would prove it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies @Gerbenny. I'll try fix the issue updating my css as your advice.